# How to manage the hidden state dims when using pad_sequence?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, lstm, padding, recurrent-neural-network

Using Pytorch LSTM architecture trying to build a text generation model. For every batch, I'm using pad_sequence to have min padding for every sequence, therefore I have a variable dims batch (batch_size * seq_len). I'm applying also pack_padded_seq to only give the non-zero (non-padding) tokens to the LSTM. But, the variable dims batch throws an error while feeding it to the LSTM as following; **Expected hidden[0] size (1, 8, 16), got (1, 16, 16)**. In this error, I have provided batch size 16 with 8 tokens for every sequence, but the hidden state is 16 * 16.

I have tried to create the hidden state in the forward function, but that did not work well. How can I create the hidden state such that it can accept variable dims batch and it will not be lost for the whole epoche?

```
class RNNModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_vocab, seq_size, embedding_size, lstm_size):
        super(RNNModule, self).__init__()
        self.seq_size = seq_size
        self.lstm_size = lstm_size
        self.embedding, num_embeddings, embedding_dim = create_emb_layer(weight_matrix, False)        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_size,
                        lstm_size,
                        num_layers=flags.n_layers,
                        batch_first=True
                        )
        self.dense = nn.Linear(lstm_size, n_vocab)

    def forward(self, x,length,prev_state):

        embed = self.embedding(x)
        packed_input = db.pack_src(embed,length)
        packed_output, state = self.lstm(packed_input,prev_state)
        padded,_ = db.pad_pack(packed_output) 
        logits = self.dense(padded)
        return logits, state


    def zero_state(self, batch_size = flags.batch_size):
        return (torch.zeros(flags.n_layers, batch_size, self.lstm_size),
            torch.zeros(flags.n_layers, batch_size, self.lstm_size))


input: tensor([[  19,    9,    4,    3,   68,    8,    6,    2],
    [  19,    9,    4,    3,    7,    8,    6,    2],
    [   3,   12,   17,   10,    6,   40,    2,    0],
    [   4,    3,  109,    7,    6,    2,    0,    0],
    [ 188,    6,    7,   18,    3,    2,    0,    0],
    [   4,    3,   12,    6,    7,    2,    0,    0],
    [   6,    7,    3,   13,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   3,   28,   17,   69,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   6,    3,   12,   11,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   3,   13,    6,    7,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   3,    6,    7,   13,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   6,    3,   23,    7,    2,    0,    0,    0],
    [   3,   28,   10,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   6,    3,   23,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   3,    6,   37,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0],
    [1218,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
```

Zero tokens are padding.
Embedding size: 64
LSTM size: 16
batch size: 16

Comment: Please provide more details about the LSTM and your inputs, such as the creation of the LSTM with the concrete parameters and the sizes of the inputs.

Comment: @MichaelJungo I have modified the q

Comment: I managed to reproduce the error, and it's certainly related to the packing, but you are using a custom packing with `db.pack_src`, I'm expecting that you're calling [`nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence) in there. Could you also post that implementation?

Comment: I have debugged the packing so that it works as it's intended to be (removing paddings and concatenating the sequences as needed).
    def pack_src(seld,embed,length):
        return rnn_utils.pack_padded_sequence(embed,length,batch_first=False)
Btw, the lstm runs when I initiate a hidden state with the dims that corrosponds to each inputed batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the hidden state you create has the correct size, but your input does not. When you pack it with [`nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence) you've set `batch_first=False`, but your data has size *[batch_size, seq_len, embedding_size]* when you pass it to the packing, so that has batch_size as the first dimension. Also for the LSTM you use `batch_first=True`, which is appropriate for your data.

You only need to pack it correctly by setting `batch_first=True` as well, to match the order of your data.

```py
rnn_utils.pack_padded_sequence(embed,length,batch_first=True)
```

Comment: But, then the sequence obtained from the packing is not what it's supposed to be. This is the packed sequence of the input mentioned in the questions which is wrong and not as its supposed to be. [  19,   19,    3,    4,  188,    4,    6,    3,    6,    3,    3,    6,
           3,    6,    3, 1218,    9,    9,   12,    3,    6,    3,    7,   28,
           3,   13,    6,    3,   28,    3,    6,    2,    4,    4,   17,  109,
           7,   12,    3,   17,   12,    6,    7,   23,   10,   23,   37,    3 ...]

Comment: I think it should be the sequence as in the input just dropping the zeros concatenated together. which is then it will have something similar to this [  19,    9,    4,    3,   68,    8,    6,    2, 19,    9,    4,    3,    7,    8,    6,    2 ....]
Am I wrong here?

Comment: No, the packing does not work like that. They are grouped by the i-th element, so you get all 0th elements, then all 1st, etc. And `packed.batch_sizes` tells you how many elements belong to that particular time step, or equivalently: how many of the sequences in the batch are not yet finished.